# How to mock a 3rd party module that is just a function ('js-file-download')

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

I'm trying to write a test around download functionality in a React component that uses 'js-file-download'. I have been able to mock it a couple ways in my test:

```
import fileDownload from 'js-file-download'

jest.mock('js-file-download', () => jest.fn(console.trace))
// or
jest.mock('js-file-download', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(console.trace)
  }
})
```

both seem to work in that it prints a trace that looks correct. However:

```
expect(fileDownload).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

fails:

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Anyone know why it appears to call the mock, but doesn't register that it was called? Is there another way to tackle this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you execute the `fileDownload` function?

Comment: Yeah, it's imported and happens in the code under test, and the trace indicates that it is happening correctly. Also if I dump `fileDownload` in the test where I check that it was called it is a mock object. But it's like I have two mock instances, one in the code being tested, and the other in the testcase... is that possible? But if I try to do something like. `const mockFileDownload = jest.fn(); jest.mock('js-file-download', () => mockFileDownload)` I get `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockFileDownload' before initialization`

Comment: I tried adding `jest.spyOn(fileDownload, 'default')`, but it still didn't register the call.

Comment: I think this is a timing issue. I added some logging at the point of the call in code and at the point of verify in test, and verify happens first, plus I can see .mock.calls at the point of call. 'waitFor' might clear things up, but unfortunately another 3rd party library has trouble with that.

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue ? I am facing the same issue. :(

Comment: The issue was waiting on the call using 'await waitFor'. I don't recall the specifics of the other problem that was preventing me from doing that. I'm using my 2nd version of the mock with __esModule: true

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to fix `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockFileDownload' before initialization`

```
const mockFileDownload = jest.fn();
jest.mock('js-file-download', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: () => mockFileDownload()
}));
```

To get the assertion to work we have to use `waitFor()`

```
....
await waitFor(() => {
    expect(mockFileDownload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had it mocked correctly all along. The real issue was the timing and whatever was preventing me using 'await waitFor' as that was the key.

```
import mockFileDownload from 'js-file-download'

jest.mock('js-file-download', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn()
}))

...

await waitFor(() => expect(mockFileDownload).toBeCalled())
```